# putbucket and putobject not working. Getting blank screen after clicking on upload button

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I am following tutorial to upload image file on amazon s3 which i made before executing this code. But when i load the page using localhost i am seeing a blank screen. Don't know why.
I tried to remove lines in the php code. I guess something is going wrong while instantiating the S3 constructor but not sure.
I also tried to upload file using php on my localhost (not amazon) there also i found such case.
So guys where is the problem residing?
Please help me. I am stuck.

```
 <?php
$bucketname="myname";
if(!class_exists('S3')) require_once('S3.php');

if(!defined('awsAccessKey')) define('awsAccessKey','key');
if(!defined('awsSecretKey')) define('awsSecretKey','secretkey');

$s3= new S3(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey);

if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $fileName= $_FILES['theFile']['name'];
    $fileTempName= $_FILES['theFile']['tmp_name'];

    $s3->putBucket($bucketname, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    //if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName,$bucketname,$fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
    //{
    //  echo "We successfully uploaded your file.";
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //  echo "something went wrong";
    //}

    try
    {
        $s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName,$bucketname,$fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
            echo $e->getMessage();

    }
}

?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="theFile" type="file" />
    <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Upload"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pit looks like you are mixing HTML and php

```
    $s3->putBucket($bucketname, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);<br><br>
```

Also this line looks wrong

```
if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName,$bucketname,$fileName, Se::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
```

Should it be

```
    if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName,$bucketname,$fileName, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ)
```

You need to carefully check your php syntax. Perhaps put some echo statements in the code to output some debugging info. You could also put a try catch around the code

```
try
{
   $s3->putObjectFile(params);
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
 }
```

Comment: it displays blank screen not even the form :(

Comment: changed se to s3 but still blank screen. When i comment lines involving $s3 i can see the form.

Comment: Add in the s3 commands one at a time, starting from the top until you find out which one is failing.

Comment: i did as you said. putObjectFile is not working. Others are working fine.

Comment: used code shown above. But after clicking the upload button i see blank screen not even error message.

Comment: when i echoed the temp locatin it gave 'var/wwww/tmp/phpVPjYCe'. IS there any problem with the permission 777 or something. I am using ubuntu

Comment: I am getting same issue .. image have 777 permission and php syntax
try
     {
        $s3->putObjectFile($url, $bucketName , $filename, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ);
     }
     catch(Exception $e)
     {
      echo $e->getMessage();
      }

Comment: On localhost getObjectInfo works but putObjectFile doesnt work on localhost, same code works on Production server. Any idea?